# mysqli can't fetch database?

Tags: php

Apparently My database function can't fetch the database?

Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch database

I've created a custom database class which extends MySQLi.

Here's how I'm constructing it.

```
public function __construct(){
    $db = new mysqli(
        DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    $db->select_db(DB_NAME);
    return $db;
}
```

I am selecting the database, aren't I?

The code where this is happening is here:

```
    private static function readSession($sessionId)
    {
    global $database;
    $sessionId = session_id();
    $sessionId = $database->real_escape_string($sessionId);
    $time = time();
    $result = $database->query("SELECT sessiondata FROM sessions WHERE sessionid='$sessionId' AND expiry > $time");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        return $row['sessiondata'];
    }
    return "";
}
```

The database is being initiated before the Session Management functions are being called.

Comment: Post the code where you are attempting to call `real_escape_string()`.  Have you established your database connection by instantiating the above class when you call it? If not, it won't work. You must have an active connection.

Comment: You don't need to call `select_db()` after connecting, as you have already selected the database in the `new mysqli()` constructor

Comment: Oh, I see you are returning `$db` in the constructor. Don't do that. The constructor implicitly returns the object.  Please post the rest of your code for more context.

Comment: You most likely need to define $db outside of your function so all other functions have access to it.

Comment: I am new to mysqli but aren't you selecting db twice.Once during creating an instance and then again using select_db

Comment: If this class extends mysqli, you should be doing `parent::__construct(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);`

Comment: The current does select the database twice, because I thought it wasn't select it at all, it's just an artefact from my testing. the same with the returning of `$db`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that your custom class extends mysqli.  If that is the case, you need to call the mysqli `__construct()` in your extending constructor, without returning anything:

```
class YourDatabase extends mysqli {
  public function __construct() {
    // Call the mysqli constructor explictly
    parent::__construct(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    // No need to call select_db() again, since default db was selected in the 
    // parent constructor

    // Don't return anything
    // the constructor returns $this, which extends mysqli
    return;
  }
}

// Use as:
$database = new YourClass();
$database->query("SELECT * FROM atable");
```

Extending a class means that you are using a descendent of the parent class. You do not need to instantiate an instance of the parent class, but if you need to make use of its constructor and extend its functionality, you must explicitly call `parent::__construct(...)` in the child class's `__construct()`.